# Merge to stl unordered_maps with a movable, non copyable value type

Tags: c++, stl, move, unordered-map

When I have two containers:

```
unordered_map<string, CopyableType> a, b;
```

I can do:

```
b.insert(a.begin(), a.end());
```

But with a movable only type such as :

```
unordered_map<string, unique_ptr<CopyableType>> a, b;
```

This does not work of course, as we can't copy the values. I have tried with a move_iterator, but this does not help. Why and how may I achieve this?

```
b.insert(move_iterator(a.begin()), move_iterator(a.end()));
```

Comment: *make_* move_iterator

Comment: or in c++17 `b.merge(std::move(a));`